# DSX notification if scheduled notebook does not run?

Tags: ibm-cloud, data-science-experience, dsx

I'm trying to troubleshoot an hourly scheduled notebook as per this question: 
[How to troubleshoot a DSX scheduled notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479504/how-to-troubleshoot-a-dsx-scheduled-notebook)

When listing the kernel logs I noticed at 3am the notebook was not scheduled:

```
kernel-pyspark-20170104_230002.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_010001.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_020000.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_040001.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_050009.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_060001.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_070001.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_080001.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_090001.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_100001.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_110002.log
kernel-pyspark-20170105_120002.log
```

Can I enable notifications so that I am alerted (e.g. by email) when a scheduled notebook does not run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not available as of now. But sounds like an improvement. You can add it as an `Idea` here: https://datascix.uservoice.com/forums/387207-general/filters/top