# Scheduled job does not appear to run and no kernel files are created

Tags: dsx, data-science-experience

I have a scheduled notebook job that has been running without issue for a number of days, however, last night it stopped running.  Note that I am able to run the job manually without issue.

I raised a previous question on this topic: [How to troubleshoot a DSX scheduled notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479504/how-to-troubleshoot-a-dsx-scheduled-notebook)

Following the above instructions, I noticed that there were no log files created at the times when the job should have run.   Because I'm able to run the job manually and there are no kernel logs created at the times the schedule job should have run, I'm presuming there is an issue with the scheduler service.

Are there any other steps I can perform to investigate this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with the Scheduling service. I recommend to take it up with DSX support. *Currently* there is no management UX telling you why a specific job failed or letting you restart a particular execution (that would be a good fit for an enhancement request to provide via https://datascix.uservoice.com/).